# Get next utf8 character size in Python using built-in function or 3rd party library?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, hex, hex-editors

I am developing a hex editor in Python using PySide, its left side panel is hex viewer, and right side panel is decoded text viewer (by different encodings).

My current working functionality is to display the binary data as text using utf8 encoding. Certainly I can just decode the whole line using

```
line.decode('utf8', 'ignore')
```

While in this way there will be no spacing between each utf8 character.

---

But I need add white spaces between characters if the character's byte size is greater than 1.

e.g.

Bytes "61 e4 bd a0 e5 a5 bd" decoded to utf8 will be 3 characters: a(61), 你(e4 bd a0), 好(e5 a5 bd)
So what I want to display will be like:

(Hex Editor)

61 e4 bd a0 e5 a5 bd ...   | a 你_ _ 好_ _ ... (underscore means spaces)

---

So I need get next utf8 character's byte size to decide how many white spaces needed be added.

Assume the function is called *nextUtf8CharSize*(bytes)

The pseudo code to decode one line of bytes will be

```
i = 0
while i < 16: # 16 bytes in one line
  size = nextUtf8CharSize(bytes)
  text = bytes[i:i+size].decode('utf8')
  spaces = ''.join([' ' for j in range(size)])
  text += spaces
  i += size
```

Is there any bulit-in function or 3rd party library to do this job? (Otherwise I need to implement it myself)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you can't just re-encode?

Comment: I've duped you to a question where I explain how to distinguish between UTF-8 starting and continuation bytes. If `byte & 0xC0 == 0x80` is true you have a continuation byte, otherwise you have a starting byte.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try the methods you mentioned.